# Remove borders from a QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to generate a new app interface using `qt` libreries. This interface requieres some frames and layouts in orther to look good. Here is what I have in the designer Window (QT module of my `ui` object).

[image: Designer View]

As you can see, there are three frames that allows me to draw borders around some properties I want to group (I don't want to use a `GroupBox`). The problem appears when I run the application. When the window appears, the `ui` object draws the border of some GridLayouts (not all of them) and I don't understand why...

I googled for some reason but I can't find why this is happening. Everybody says that layouts are not grphical objects so they can't have any border arround them. However, that's what I'm getting when I run the application:

[image: Runtime view]

Here is the code of my UI object:

```
class Ui_MainFrameClass
{
public:
    QWidget *gridLayoutWidget;
    QGridLayout *GridMain;
    QGridLayout *GridModelWash;
    QFrame *FrameWash;
    QTreeWidget *TreeWashProgram;
    QLabel *LWashProgramTitle;
    QFrame *FrameModel;
    QWidget *gridLayoutWidget_4;
    QGridLayout *GridModel;
    QGridLayout *GridQR;
    QGridLayout *GridQRProperties;
    QLabel *LQRCodeTitle;
    QLabel *LQRCode;
    QLabel *LQRBitmap;
    QGridLayout *GridModelProperties;
    QLabel *LSize;
    QLabel *LWeightTitle;
    QLabel *LModel;
    QLabel *LProductTitle;
    QLabel *LModelTitle;
    QLabel *LSizeTitle;
    QLabel *LWeight;
    QLabel *LBaseColorTitle;
    QLabel *LBaseColor;
    QLabel *LProduct;
    QLabel *LLogoBaseColorTitle;
    QLabel *LLogoBaseColor;
    QSpacerItem *Spacer2;
    QFrame *FrameColorButtons;
    QWidget *gridLayoutWidget_3;
    QGridLayout *GridColorButtons;
    QGridLayout *GridButtons;
    QPushButton *BNew;
    QPushButton *BColor;
    QGridLayout *GridFinalColor;
    QProgressBar *PBColor2;
    QProgressBar *PBColor1;
    QProgressBar *PBColor3;
    QLabel *LColor1;
    QLabel *LColor2;
    QLabel *LColor3;
    QGridLayout *GridColorRatios;
    QLabel *LColorPreviewTitle;
    QLabel *LColorNameTitle;
    QLabel *LColorRefTitle;
    QLabel *LColorName;
    QLabel *LColorReference;
    QLabel *LColorPreview;
    QSpacerItem *Spacer1;

    void setupUi(QWidget *MainFrameClass)
    {
        if (MainFrameClass->objectName().isEmpty())
            MainFrameClass->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("MainFrameClass"));
        MainFrameClass->resize(803, 602);
        MainFrameClass->setStyleSheet(QStringLiteral("background-color: #f7f7f7;"));
        gridLayoutWidget = new QWidget(MainFrameClass);
        gridLayoutWidget->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("gridLayoutWidget"));
        gridLayoutWidget->setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 781, 581));
        GridMain = new QGridLayout(gridLayoutWidget);
        GridMain->setSpacing(6);
        GridMain->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        GridMain->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("GridMain"));
        GridMain->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        GridModelWash = new QGridLayout();
        GridModelWash->setSpacing(6);
        GridModelWash->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("GridModelWash"));
        FrameWash = new QFrame(gridLayoutWidget);
        FrameWash->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("FrameWash"));
        FrameWash->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 2px solid #00a6ce;\n"
"border-radius: 15px;"));
        FrameWash->setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);
        FrameWash->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);
        TreeWashProgram = new QTreeWidget(FrameWash);
        QTreeWidgetItem *__qtreewidgetitem = new QTreeWidgetItem();
        __qtreewidgetitem->setText(0, QStringLiteral("1"));
        TreeWashProgram->setHeaderItem(__qtreewidgetitem);
        TreeWashProgram->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("TreeWashProgram"));
        TreeWashProgram->setGeometry(QRect(10, 50, 256, 291));
        TreeWashProgram->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px\n"
""));
        LWashProgramTitle = new QLabel(FrameWash);
        LWashProgramTitle->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LWashProgramTitle"));
        LWashProgramTitle->setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 251, 31));
        LWashProgramTitle->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));

        GridModelWash->addWidget(FrameWash, 0, 2, 1, 1);

        FrameModel = new QFrame(gridLayoutWidget);
        FrameModel->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("FrameModel"));
        FrameModel->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 2px solid #00a6ce;\n"
"border-radius: 15px;"));
        FrameModel->setFrameShape(QFrame::StyledPanel);
        FrameModel->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);
        gridLayoutWidget_4 = new QWidget(FrameModel);
        gridLayoutWidget_4->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("gridLayoutWidget_4"));
        gridLayoutWidget_4->setGeometry(QRect(30, 20, 461, 331));
        GridModel = new QGridLayout(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        GridModel->setSpacing(6);
        GridModel->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        GridModel->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("GridModel"));
        GridModel->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        GridQR = new QGridLayout();
        GridQR->setSpacing(6);
        GridQR->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("GridQR"));
        GridQRProperties = new QGridLayout();
        GridQRProperties->setSpacing(6);
        GridQRProperties->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("GridQRProperties"));
        LQRCodeTitle = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LQRCodeTitle->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LQRCodeTitle"));
        LQRCodeTitle->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));

        GridQRProperties->addWidget(LQRCodeTitle, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        LQRCode = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LQRCode->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LQRCode"));
        LQRCode->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LQRCode->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter);

        GridQRProperties->addWidget(LQRCode, 0, 1, 1, 1);


        GridQR->addLayout(GridQRProperties, 1, 0, 1, 1);

        LQRBitmap = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LQRBitmap->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LQRBitmap"));
        LQRBitmap->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LQRBitmap->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

        GridQR->addWidget(LQRBitmap, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        GridQR->setRowStretch(0, 7);
        GridQR->setRowStretch(1, 3);

        GridModel->addLayout(GridQR, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        GridModelProperties = new QGridLayout();
        GridModelProperties->setSpacing(6);
        GridModelProperties->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("GridModelProperties"));
        GridModelProperties->setContentsMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        LSize = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LSize->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LSize"));
        LSize->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LSize->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter);

        GridModelProperties->addWidget(LSize, 2, 1, 1, 1);

        LWeightTitle = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LWeightTitle->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LWeightTitle"));
        LWeightTitle->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));

        GridModelProperties->addWidget(LWeightTitle, 3, 0, 1, 1);

        LModel = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LModel->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LModel"));
        LModel->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LModel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter);

        GridModelProperties->addWidget(LModel, 1, 1, 1, 1);

        LProductTitle = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LProductTitle->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LProductTitle"));
        LProductTitle->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));

        GridModelProperties->addWidget(LProductTitle, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        LModelTitle = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LModelTitle->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LModelTitle"));
        LModelTitle->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));

        GridModelProperties->addWidget(LModelTitle, 1, 0, 1, 1);

        LSizeTitle = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LSizeTitle->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LSizeTitle"));
        LSizeTitle->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));

        GridModelProperties->addWidget(LSizeTitle, 2, 0, 1, 1);

        LWeight = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LWeight->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LWeight"));
        LWeight->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LWeight->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter);

        GridModelProperties->addWidget(LWeight, 3, 1, 1, 1);

        LBaseColorTitle = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LBaseColorTitle->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LBaseColorTitle"));
        LBaseColorTitle->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));

        GridModelProperties->addWidget(LBaseColorTitle, 4, 0, 1, 1);

        LBaseColor = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LBaseColor->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LBaseColor"));
        LBaseColor->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LBaseColor->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter);

        GridModelProperties->addWidget(LBaseColor, 4, 1, 1, 1);

        LProduct = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LProduct->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LProduct"));
        LProduct->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LProduct->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter);

        GridModelProperties->addWidget(LProduct, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        LLogoBaseColorTitle = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LLogoBaseColorTitle->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LLogoBaseColorTitle"));
        LLogoBaseColorTitle->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));

        GridModelProperties->addWidget(LLogoBaseColorTitle, 5, 0, 1, 1);

        LLogoBaseColor = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_4);
        LLogoBaseColor->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LLogoBaseColor"));
        LLogoBaseColor->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LLogoBaseColor->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter);

        GridModelProperties->addWidget(LLogoBaseColor, 5, 1, 1, 1);


        GridModel->addLayout(GridModelProperties, 0, 1, 1, 1);


        GridModelWash->addWidget(FrameModel, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        Spacer2 = new QSpacerItem(10, 20, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Minimum);

        GridModelWash->addItem(Spacer2, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        GridModelWash->setColumnStretch(0, 7);
        GridModelWash->setColumnStretch(2, 4);

        GridMain->addLayout(GridModelWash, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        FrameColorButtons = new QFrame(gridLayoutWidget);
        FrameColorButtons->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("FrameColorButtons"));
        FrameColorButtons->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 2px solid #00a6ce;\n"
"border-radius: 15px;"));
        FrameColorButtons->setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);
        FrameColorButtons->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Raised);
        gridLayoutWidget_3 = new QWidget(FrameColorButtons);
        gridLayoutWidget_3->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("gridLayoutWidget_3"));
        gridLayoutWidget_3->setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 761, 181));
        GridColorButtons = new QGridLayout(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        GridColorButtons->setSpacing(6);
        GridColorButtons->setContentsMargins(11, 11, 11, 11);
        GridColorButtons->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("GridColorButtons"));
        GridColorButtons->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        GridButtons = new QGridLayout();
        GridButtons->setSpacing(6);
        GridButtons->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("GridButtons"));
        BNew = new QPushButton(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        BNew->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("BNew"));
        QSizePolicy sizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0);
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(BNew->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        BNew->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
        BNew->setMinimumSize(QSize(120, 60));
        BNew->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #c7c7c7;\n"
"border-radius: 7px;\n"
"font: bold 75 12pt \"VAG Rounded Std\";\n"
"background-color: #c7c7c7\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"background-color:#00a6ce;\n"
"border: 2px solid #00a6ce;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"background-color:#00a6ce;\n"
"border: 2px solid #00a6ce;\n"
"font: bold 75 11pt \"VAG Rounded Std\";\n"
"}"));

        GridButtons->addWidget(BNew, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        BColor = new QPushButton(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        BColor->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("BColor"));
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(BColor->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        BColor->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
        BColor->setMinimumSize(QSize(120, 60));
        BColor->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("QPushButton{\n"
"border: 2px solid #c7c7c7;\n"
"border-radius: 7px;\n"
"font: bold 75 12pt \"VAG Rounded Std\";\n"
"background-color: #c7c7c7\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:hover{\n"
"background-color:#00a6ce;\n"
"border: 2px solid #00a6ce;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QPushButton:pressed{\n"
"background-color:#00a6ce;\n"
"border: 2px solid #00a6ce;\n"
"font: bold 75 11pt \"VAG Rounded Std\";\n"
"}"));

        GridButtons->addWidget(BColor, 1, 0, 1, 1);


        GridColorButtons->addLayout(GridButtons, 0, 2, 1, 1);

        GridFinalColor = new QGridLayout();
        GridFinalColor->setSpacing(6);
        GridFinalColor->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("GridFinalColor"));
        PBColor2 = new QProgressBar(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        PBColor2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("PBColor2"));
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(PBColor2->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        PBColor2->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
        PBColor2->setMinimumSize(QSize(250, 0));
        PBColor2->setValue(24);
        PBColor2->setTextVisible(false);

        GridFinalColor->addWidget(PBColor2, 1, 0, 1, 1);

        PBColor1 = new QProgressBar(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        PBColor1->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("PBColor1"));
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(PBColor1->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        PBColor1->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
        PBColor1->setMinimumSize(QSize(250, 0));
        PBColor1->setValue(24);
        PBColor1->setTextVisible(false);

        GridFinalColor->addWidget(PBColor1, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        PBColor3 = new QProgressBar(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        PBColor3->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("PBColor3"));
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(PBColor3->sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth());
        PBColor3->setSizePolicy(sizePolicy);
        PBColor3->setMinimumSize(QSize(250, 0));
        PBColor3->setValue(24);
        PBColor3->setTextVisible(false);

        GridFinalColor->addWidget(PBColor3, 2, 0, 1, 1);

        LColor1 = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        LColor1->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LColor1"));
        LColor1->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LColor1->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

        GridFinalColor->addWidget(LColor1, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        LColor2 = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        LColor2->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LColor2"));
        LColor2->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LColor2->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

        GridFinalColor->addWidget(LColor2, 1, 1, 1, 1);

        LColor3 = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        LColor3->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LColor3"));
        LColor3->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LColor3->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);

        GridFinalColor->addWidget(LColor3, 2, 1, 1, 1);

        GridFinalColor->setRowStretch(0, 5);
        GridFinalColor->setRowStretch(1, 5);
        GridFinalColor->setRowStretch(2, 5);

        GridColorButtons->addLayout(GridFinalColor, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        GridColorRatios = new QGridLayout();
        GridColorRatios->setSpacing(6);
        GridColorRatios->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("GridColorRatios"));
        LColorPreviewTitle = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        LColorPreviewTitle->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LColorPreviewTitle"));
        LColorPreviewTitle->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));

        GridColorRatios->addWidget(LColorPreviewTitle, 2, 0, 1, 1);

        LColorNameTitle = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        LColorNameTitle->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LColorNameTitle"));
        LColorNameTitle->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));

        GridColorRatios->addWidget(LColorNameTitle, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        LColorRefTitle = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        LColorRefTitle->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LColorRefTitle"));
        LColorRefTitle->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));

        GridColorRatios->addWidget(LColorRefTitle, 1, 0, 1, 1);

        LColorName = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        LColorName->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LColorName"));
        LColorName->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LColorName->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter);

        GridColorRatios->addWidget(LColorName, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        LColorReference = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        LColorReference->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LColorReference"));
        LColorReference->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LColorReference->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter);

        GridColorRatios->addWidget(LColorReference, 1, 1, 1, 1);

        LColorPreview = new QLabel(gridLayoutWidget_3);
        LColorPreview->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("LColorPreview"));
        LColorPreview->setStyleSheet(QLatin1String("border: 0px;\n"
"border-radius: 0px;"));
        LColorPreview->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignTrailing|Qt::AlignVCenter);

        GridColorRatios->addWidget(LColorPreview, 2, 1, 1, 1);

        GridColorRatios->setRowStretch(0, 5);
        GridColorRatios->setRowStretch(1, 5);
        GridColorRatios->setRowStretch(2, 5);

        GridColorButtons->addLayout(GridColorRatios, 0, 1, 1, 1);

        GridColorButtons->setColumnStretch(0, 6);
        GridColorButtons->setColumnStretch(1, 4);
        GridColorButtons->setColumnStretch(2, 3);

        GridMain->addWidget(FrameColorButtons, 2, 0, 1, 1);

        Spacer1 = new QSpacerItem(20, 10, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Fixed);

        GridMain->addItem(Spacer1, 1, 0, 1, 1);

        GridMain->setRowStretch(0, 7);
        GridMain->setRowStretch(2, 4);

        retranslateUi(MainFrameClass);

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(MainFrameClass);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QWidget *MainFrameClass)
    {
        MainFrameClass->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "Rainbow - Jeanologia", 0));
        LWashProgramTitle->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "Wash program:", 0));
        LQRCodeTitle->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "TextLabel", 0));
        LQRCode->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "TextLabel", 0));
        LQRBitmap->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "TextLabel", 0));
        LSize->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "Medium", 0));
        LWeightTitle->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "Weight", 0));
        LModel->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "Jeanologia 2020-04", 0));
        LProductTitle->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "Product", 0));
        LModelTitle->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "Model", 0));
        LSizeTitle->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "Size", 0));
        LWeight->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "254 g.", 0));
        LBaseColorTitle->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "Base color", 0));
        LBaseColor->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "Pure white", 0));
        LProduct->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "Polo", 0));
        LLogoBaseColorTitle->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "Logo base color", 0));
        LLogoBaseColor->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "Pure black", 0));
        BNew->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "NEW ITEM", 0));
        BColor->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "COLOR", 0));
        LColor1->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "TextLabel", 0));
        LColor2->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "TextLabel", 0));
        LColor3->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "TextLabel", 0));
        LColorPreviewTitle->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "TextLabel", 0));
        LColorNameTitle->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "TextLabel", 0));
        LColorRefTitle->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "TextLabel", 0));
        LColorName->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "TextLabel", 0));
        LColorReference->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "TextLabel", 0));
        LColorPreview->setText(QApplication::translate("MainFrameClass", "TextLabel", 0));
    } // retranslateUi

};
```

Can anybody tell me why those two layouts have one graphical border and what I have to do to remove it? thanks.

Comment: It is possible that the style sheet of the frame that contains the layout it is applied to the layout too? How can I avoid iit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I could find the reason why this is happening. I define the style sheet of the frame as:

```
border: 2px solid #00a6ce;
border-radius: 15px;
```

This works fine for the frame but not for the layout. However, in this style sheet the object I want to modify is not define so, I supose, the Layout defined inside this frame, inherit the same style. I define the next style sheet, it works fine in both objects:

```
QFrame{
border: 2px solid #00a6ce;
border-radius: 15px;
}
```